# How to create a matrix of p-values in ks.test

Tags: r, testing, matrix

I'am new with R. If you could help me that would be great. My problem is as follows. I have this code:

```
N <- 1000   # number of simulations
n <- 30
prob <- 0.001
Y2 <- rep(0, times=N)

for(i in 1:N) {
X <- rbinom(n, size=1, prob)    

#binomial experiment
Y2[i] <- sum(X)
}
table(Y2)

library(dgof)
ks.test(Y2, "pnorm", mean=prob*n, sd=sqrt(n*prob*(1-prob)))
```

I want to generete this code 10 times, so I'll get 10 different p-values and D. Also the parameter n will be not fixed, but it will be a vector of values (50,100,500,1000,5000). So I want a matrix of ks.test like on a picture.
Thx.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9BYX.png)